# How to structure large Laravel Livewire component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have 1 component which is growing large, component consists of filter properties (selected and all available from DB). How to properly structure my code in this case? I cant split it into multiple smaller components because as stated in documentation "props will lose reactivity" which is mandatory for such kind of functionality (ads filter). Here is what I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: did you try using laravel blade components??

Comment: You can split into multiple components, but will make a little harder to make everything reactive because you'll need to use a lot of events to make it work. You can split this public data into traits and use in your component. You also can create a single associative array with all it's data and manipulate dinamically, like just declare a public $data = [] and its wire model will handle the $data = ['category' => ['some-product']] etc